# Is it possible to plot time series on top of a heat map in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts heat map and would like to plot several line series / spline curves on top of the heat map. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have tried it quicker than you could have asked the question.

It works just fine, no need to overlaying plots or use other tricks.  Just configure each series as the appropriate type:

```
series: [{
        type: 'heatmap',
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0,0,10],[0,1,19],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],[1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48],[2,0,35],[2,1,15],[2,2,123],[2,3,64],[2,4,52],[3,0,72],[3,1,132],[3,2,114],[3,3,19],[3,4,16],[4,0,38],[4,1,5],[4,2,8],[4,3,117],[4,4,115],[5,0,88],[5,1,32],[5,2,12],[5,3,6],[5,4,120],[6,0,13],[6,1,44],[6,2,88],[6,3,98],[6,4,96],[7,0,31],[7,1,1],[7,2,82],[7,3,32],[7,4,30],[8,0,85],[8,1,97],[8,2,123],[8,3,64],[8,4,84],[9,0,47],[9,1,114],[9,2,31],[9,3,48],[9,4,91]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'black',
            style: {
                textShadow: 'none',
                HcTextStroke: null
            }
        }
    },
   {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'line',
        data: [3, 2.67, 3, 1.33, 1.33, 3.2, 1.6, 2.5, 1.4, 0.2],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },
   },
   {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'spline',
        data: [3.5, 1.67, 2, 0.33, 3.33, 1.2, 2.6, 0.5, 2.4, 1.2],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            fillColor: 'blue'
        }
    }]
```

Produces:

[image]

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t5jQB/).

Comment: You are right, I should have tried it properly before asking. Sorry for taking your time and big thanks for the answer! PS: It was my first question in stackoverflow =)

Comment: @quirion, no worries, I have been on the site to long, it makes your cranky after a while.

Comment: @Mark just curious why the spline/line data points are not in the dead center of the heatmap cells or on the borders. Some are in the center and the majority are at some other location.

Comment: @wergeld, because I used decimals values.  `ints` would center both vertically and horizontally: http://jsfiddle.net/t5jQB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use CSS positioning to overlay two charts, one being the heat map and one the lines.  Obviously the top one will need to have the chart background color set to transparent.